# What is the best way to illustrate the recovery of an extraction method?

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, extraction, mass-spectrometry

I'm currently working on PFAS (perfluoroalkyl compounds) extraction from soils and their analysis by HPLC-MS/MS.

I wonder what kind of graph can be the best to illustrate the recovery of the method. I have tried with a boxplot on R and I think it's interesting because it shows the variability between all the soils that I used for the validation. The problem is that if their is different recovery between this matrixes (depending on the physico-parameter of the soils) we can't see it neither identify it.

[image]

What do you think about it?  According to you, what is the best way to illustrate recovery and how can I do it on R?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: It would maybe help if you can state more clearly what it is that you are interested in. If I understand it correctly, you want to plot the recovery against a physochemical property?